# Why I get brackets different in the size?

Tags: macros, equations, brackets

I typed

```
\begin{gather*}
\frac1{1-x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[H_n^3-3H_nH_n^{(2)}+2H_n^{(3)}-\left(H_n- 
\frac1n\right)^3\right.\\
\left.+3\left(H_n-\frac1n\right)\left(H_{n}^{(2)}-\frac1{n^2}\right)-2\left(H_{n}^{(3)}- 
\frac1{n^3}\right)\right]x^n
\end{gather*}
```

and I got this ( ignore the equal sign in the picture)

[image: different size]

---

My question is why the square brackets are different in the size? Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's worth placing the two main code chunks from lines 1 and 2 on the same line:

[image]

In the first code chunk, the expression

```
\left(H_n-\frac1n\right)
```

is raised to the third power -- highlighted in orange in the screenshot posted above.

In contrast, the three `\left(...\right)` terms in the second chunk do not get squared or cubed. As a result, the single tallest object inside `\left[...\right.` in line 1 is slightly taller than the single tallest object inside `\left. ... \right]` in line 2.

The upshot? TeX sees fit to make `\left[` in line 1 taller than `\right]` in line 2.

The remedy? Don't overuse `\left` and `\right`. For the two-line equation at hand, I'd use `\biggl[` on line 1 and `\biggr]` on line 2 -- and, clearly, get rid  of `\right.` on line 1 and of `\left.` on line 2 as they're no longer needed.